# How to add custom labels in donut renderer jqplot?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, jqplot

I want to add dataLabels **labels** for s1 donut and dataLabels **percent** or no label for s2.How can i do that?

[image]

```
     function drawDonut(chartId){
             var s1 = [['a',6], ['b',8], ['c',14], ['d',20]];
             var s2 = [['e', 6], ['f', 8], ['g', 14], ['h', 20]];

              var plot = $.jqplot(chartId,[s1,s2], {
                seriesDefaults: {
                  // make this a donut chart.
                  renderer:$.jqplot.DonutRenderer,
                  rendererOptions:{
                    // Donut's can be cut into slices like pies.
                    sliceMargin: 0,
                    dataLabelThreshold: 0,
                    // Pies and donuts can start at any arbitrary angle.
                    startAngle: -90,
                    showDataLabels: true,
                    // By default, data labels show the percentage of the donut/pie.
                    // You can show the data 'value' or data 'label' instead.
                    dataLabels: 'label'
                  }
                }
              }
```

Comment: seems like no one has answered this question.....

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked at the documentation, especially the [dataLabelFormatString](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/plugins/jqplot-donutRenderer-js.html#$.jqplot.DonutRenderer.dataLabelFormatString)?

Comment: @AmosM.Carpenter I have written the code i tried for, the prblem is coming that whatever label format i apply, it gets applied to both the donuts.

Comment: The sample code you posted is pretty much identical to what's on the jqplot homepage (including the comment that kills a puppy by using an apostrophe to make a plural). Have you tried anything other than changing the `dataLabels` value? You realise you can calculate the percentages yourself and just use those as your data labels for your second series, right? This library is easy to modify if you're willing to get your hands dirty.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're setting showDataLabels in seriesDefaults.  Check out http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqPlotOptions-txt.html for how to set options per series.